# What is exact time in Neo4j execution time?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, query-optimization, graph-databases

I am using Neo4j query log analyzer on Neo4j desktop to investigate my performance issue.
In the image, the total for 2nd query is 153281 ms (~ 2.5 mins); but the time for planning, cpu and waiting is very small, just 1433ms in total.

[Click here to view image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cMN75.png)

So where is the rest? I think that "total time = planning + cpu + waiting " but it seems I am wrong.

Thank you in advance

Harvey Nguyen

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check your debug logs around the time of the query's execution. Look for stop-the-world pauses.

The query execution time is a wall clock time that will include any VM pauses that happened between query start and query stop. If you see this, then depending on whether you see positive GC counts or not in the pause readout, it could indicate that there are some unoptimized queries triggering garbage collections that cause VM pauses, and you may need to do some query tuning to optimize them.

Comment: Thanks very much for your help. This the query log
2021-02-06 15:33:10.100+0000 WARN [o.n.k.i.c.VmPauseMonitorComponent] Detected VM stop-the-world pause: {pauseTime=687, gcTime=0, gcCount=0}
2021-02-06 16:01:19.595+0000 WARN [o.n.b.r.MetricsReportingBoltConnection] The client is unauthorized due to authentication failure.
2021-02-06 16:01:23.296+0000 INFO [o.n.k.NeoStoreDataSource] Rotated to transaction log [/var/lib/neo4j/data/databases/ctsdatacenter/neostore.transaction.db.2992] version=2992, last transaction in previous log=8491554

Comment: The query has run at 2021-02-06 15:57:27.245. As you mentioned, there is a "VM stop-the-world pause". So how to determine which query need to improve ?

Comment: That isn't so straightforward a question. If you cross-reference your query log with your debug log, check for queries executing a little before the stop-the-world pause (you may need to subtract the pause time from the timestamp of the pause, since it can only log when the pause ends). That said, 687ms isn't enough to explain the total execution time. Were there other pauses near that time that could sum up to near that total time?

Comment: Also reference [this query tuning section](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/query-tuning/query-options/) of our docs. You can also ask for some help on the [Neo4j community forums](https://community.neo4j.com/), though we'd need to see the query and probably a PROFILE plan of the query.

Comment: I have asked this question since 6 Feb on Neo4j forum but there is no answer :( . We can continue to discuss on this link:  https://community.neo4j.com/t/how-to-read-neo4j-query-log-analyzer-correctly/33321. Again, thank you very much for your help